# Authorship of Rabbenu Gershom's Commentary to Talmud

Tags: commentaries, rishonim, authorship, geonim

Who authored the commentary attributed to [Rabbenu Gershom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershom_ben_Judah) to tractate Temurah and other tractates such as Bava Batra?

---

I recall reading some who doubted the traditional attribution, or suggesting that the text evolved.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.academia.edu/12015181/Genizah_Fragments_from_Rabbenu_Gershoms_Commentary_on_Bava_Batra) article in Yeshurun asserts that he did not author the commentary on the talmud attributed to him, although perhaps it is based on his commentary.